# Is time ever represented as something else than a 1 dimensional line in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

Is time ever represented as something else than a 1 dimensional line in mathematics? If so, what are the purposes or applications of representing or modelling time as something else than an 1 dimensional line in mathematics? Could you provide some examples of that?

Comment: In probability theory, we often use discrete time: $\{0,1,2,3,\dots\}$.

Comment: In general relativity, _proper time_ ("elapsed time as experienced by a point particle") is effectively arc length (with respect to the spacetime metric) along the particle's world line. Consequently, proper time is not a function on spacetime, but depends on the motion of the observer.

Comment: It could be fun to have two dimensional time, where the state of the world at time (s,t) depends on the state of the world at other times (s',t') for $s' \leq s, t' \leq t$. I haven't personally seen this idea studied though.